# linking libdl is needed for dlopen(); function or not?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, dynamic-linking, dlopen

i'm currently building camerahal library for android M for my device, i dont know what the situation is with "dlopen function in android" question is that  i included `dlfcn.h`(needed for dlopen functions) into camerahal.cpp where i used dlopen functions but i didnt link against **libdl** somehow i didnt face any compile error but probably i have to link against **libdl** because docs are saying that ı must link against **libdl** with the following define `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl` [source](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#a3)

but in the following example, developer didnt link against **libdl** although he is using dlopen function

[library](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_galaxys2-common/tree/cm-13.0/ril-wrapper)

so do ı have to define on Android.mk to link against **libdl** or just defining `dlfcn.h` is enough?

Answer (score 0):

> docs are saying that ı must link against libdl
>   developer didnt link against libdl although he is using dlopen

You should *always* prefer documented approach to "it seems to work in this random example" approach.

The former is likely to continue to work. The latter is likely to stop working on next release (or the one after that).